# Serena Dimensions for Eclipse internal error while delivering: attempted to beginRule

Tags: serena

I worked locally on a major refactoring of a project of ours. It involved creating packages, removing packages, moving files, all that jazz. Of course the whole point of using Serena Dimensions is making it so that you cannot actually do so without creating a ticket, but the changes were so large that it was easier to have somebody with privileges log in on Serena from my workspace and simply commit the changes as herself.

Attempting to do so did not work. We got the following error: "attempted to beginRule". This was happening on new files in a new package, and even while logged in as her I couldn't find anything about file- or folder-specific "rules". She also had no idea what to do.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't dig to the actual cause of the issue, but it seems that there was an issue with the order of operations Dimensions attempted to commit all the changes in. I say that because we worked around the issue by delivering the changes package by package, morsel by morsel, leaving the critical package last. Delivering those changes last then worked.

This operation did leave a completely unrelated file or two in a bogus concurrent checkout status between the superuser and another team member; the superuser's web interface however only showed the team member's checkout. We performed an undo checkout from our coworker's machine (right click on file → team → show history → right click on the relevant log line → undo checkout) and *both* checkouts vanished. From then on, it was business as usual.

Comment: #justserenadimensionsthings